Why does the shape of the DataFrame change when I write in LaTeX?
When I try writing all 3 arguments of the column 'Function' in LaTex, I can only write the 2 former without having the shape of the output vary.
These are the different results:
error = (pd.DataFrame({'Function': [
        '$ f_0(x) = 1 $', 
        '$ f_1(x) = x $', 
        '$ f_2(x) = x^2 $'
    ], 
    'Error': [1, 2, 3]})
).style.set_table_styles([dict(selector = 'th', props = [('text-align', 'center')])])
error.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).hide_index()


error = (pd.DataFrame({'Function': [
        '$ f_0(x) = 1 $', 
        '$ f_1(x) = x $', 
        'f_2(x) = x^2'
    ], 
    'Error': [1, 2, 3]})
).style.set_table_styles([dict(selector = 'th', props = [('text-align', 'center')])])
error.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).hide_index()



What version of Pandas and Jupyter are you using?  The .hide_index() method is deprecated.

I'm using Jupyter 6.4.5, and importing Panda as a library.

That is a fairly old version.  It is up to 8.6.0 now.  Also, check pd.__version__

It's Panda 1.3.4.

I am not seeing this issue on the latest versions of Jupyter and pandas.  You may want to consider upgrading your packages
